# Raml same resource different query parameters

Tags: query-string, raml

i don't understand how i have to configure a raml api, to call the same resource but with different parameters:

```
www.mysite/user?uid=""
www.mysite/user?name=""&surname=""
```

Is possible to do something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The resource is the same: **/user** and you can only specify it once in your RAML.
What you can do is setting the query parameters as optional.
For example:

```
/user:
  get:
    queryParameters:
      uid:
        type: string
        required: false
      name:
        type: string
        required: false
      surname:
        type: string
        required: false
```

Or something like this:

```
#%RAML 1.0
types:
  uuid: string
  person:
    properties:
      name: string
      surname: string
/user:
  get:
    queryString:
      type: [uuid | person]
```

Comment: but if i do something like this, i have to make some control, because name and surname neeed to stay together. What can i do?

Comment: i updated my answer with a possible solution for that

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have tried a solution like this, but i'm not able to make a correct url. I have tried some solution but no one is correct.

Comment: RAML is just a specification, it does not restrict the details of your implementation, so really, what is the problem ? or are you using a code generation tool ?